# How to set tableview background color of parent view controller from inherit child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, development-environment, setbackground

How it possible to change color of overlapp tableview in child veiw controller.Here is the code but not working.......

```
  @interface ChatViewController : SOMessagingViewController

     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
          SOMessagingViewController *obj=[[SOMessagingViewController alloc]init];
          obj.tableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];

         }
```

Comment: SOMessagingViewController  is parent view controller??
I think the obj is nil have you check it?

Comment: does you set `backgroundColor` of cells in tableView to `clearColor`?

Comment: your create `obj` - new instance of SOMessagingViewController. Where are you add this obj to view hierarchy?

Comment: no object is not nil and no i doesn't set background color clear ..it by default white

Comment: cells with background color `white` hide background of tableview. Set cells background to `clearColor`

Comment: yes i already does it

Comment: Where are you add this obj to view hierarchy? I think, that you have tableView in one instance of `SOMessagingViewController `, but try to change color in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a new instance of `SOMessagingViewController`.

Simply change your code to:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Since your `ChatViewController` class extends `SOMessagingViewController`, you have access to all of the public members directly.